# Why there is so much difference between these methods of creating string

Tags: c++, string, gcc

I was going through a site to benchmark the small functions and methods in c++ for the purpose of optimization and performance and I found some results on strings that I am not able to figure out why.
Link http://quick-bench.com/mNexo7ae75tYgt8HYoB17HEHgKc for the benchmark code.

```
static void StringCreation(benchmark::State& state) {
  // Code inside this loop is measured repeatedly
  for (auto _ : state) {
    std::string created_string("hello");
    // Make sure the variable is not optimized away by compiler
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(created_string);
  }
}
// Register the function as a benchmark
BENCHMARK(StringCreation);

static void StringCreationMove(benchmark::State& state) {
  // Code inside this loop is measured repeatedly
  std::string x = "hello";
  for (auto _ : state) {
    std::string created_string_move(std::move(x));
    // Make sure the variable is not optimized away by compiler
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(created_string_move);
  }
}
// Register the function as a benchmark
BENCHMARK(StringCreationMove);

static void StringCopy(benchmark::State& state) {
  // Code before the loop is not measured
  std::string x = "hello";
  for (auto _ : state) {
    std::string copy(x.c_str());
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(copy);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(StringCopy);

static void StringCopyByChar(benchmark::State& state) {
  // Code before the loop is not measured
  const char* x = "hello";
  for (auto _ : state) {
    std::string copyChar(x);
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(copyChar);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(StringCopyByChar);
```

[image]

Comment: Do note that `std::string created_string_move(std::move(x));` is kind of pointless as you keep moving an empty string.

Comment: Seriously, a string of 5 characters is nothing, thus this benchmark is really meaningless.   For example, `std::string` has short-string optimization, and only allocates when the string is bigger than, maybe 16 bytes.  You should be testing a string with 100,000 or so characters.

Comment: A bit [longer test string](http://quick-bench.com/Ck83LqLyLnId2IF6ik352vSuzpU) and outcome is completely different (since now SSO do not kicks in). Note also that moving `x` breaks it (here it will make it empty) so test is invalid by definition.

Comment: Here is a [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/c8QY2G).

Comment: Which results are confusing? It's always a good idea to explicitly formulate a question. That's my first requirement for an upvote.

Answer (score 3):

The length of the string will have a major effect on specific results, along with things like any small string optimisation. For example it might force a "byte by byte copy" even for a "move", while avoiding the cost of any memory allocations for other operations.

also not really sure what you are expecting.

> static void StringCreation

Without optimisation the thing here is probably the need to determine the length on every iteration, as you give it a null terminated string, basically an extra `strlen` call.

But it is possible this pattern might be optimised when it sees effectively a `strlen("literal string")`, and then an allocation and copy of fixed length, and it might even see it can skip the allocation due to SSO, leaving it just to assign some fields to constant values.

GCC and Clang appear to do this, I couldn't get MSVC v142 (2019) to do this with a default /O2 release project, it optimised out the "strlen" but not the assignment itself.

> static void StringCreationMove(benchmark::State& state) {

This keeps moving from a string which after the first loop is in an unspecified state, so that could do anything from a no-op to copying the entire string. This may depend on the string length, where the implementation has small string optimizations.

> static void StringCopy(benchmark::State& state) {

By passing a `c_str()` this is like the first case, but it is unlikely any compiler will figure out the length is fixed and optimise it, assuming it is even possible within the constraints of the standard.

> static void StringCopyByChar(benchmark::State& state) {

This one is like the first case, the compiler probably figures out that your `const char` will always be the same.

Comment: If you look at the generated code, the compiler does indeed recognize the fixed length and emits a few `mov`s instead of a copy loop. You can also test this by changing `const char* x = "hello";` to `char x[] = "hello";`, which both GCC and Clang aren't clever enough to figure out is constant-length anymore, resulting in equal time to `StringCopy`.

Comment: Yeah I had a little play, as you say those two optimise it out about as much as possible for a const string, for a longer string it still optimises the size. MSVC 2019 v142 seems not to, it saw the length, but didn't want to inline a `basic_string::assign` call, so still did some checks then calls `memmove`.

Comment: @walnut I wonder why not the `char str[]` though, I can't think of any reason why the standard says it can't be as it can easily see the array is not otherwise accessed. I guess it's just not a common enough pattern to implement?

Comment: I don't think there is anything preventing the optimization. With Clang at least, you can even make the array `const` and it still doesn't optimize although there is absolute guarantee that the array is never modified. It is probably just a missed optimization opportunity.